# Why not working GC.Collect() this code? I want to Collect for Array

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I am studying garbage collection.
But I have one question.
Even though more than 2GB of array is declared and GC.Collect() is called, memory remains.
Why doesn't the GC.Collect() work?
Help me.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] array = null;
        array = new int[536870912];
        Array.Clear(array, 0, array.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Before GC Collect - GC TotalMemory: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));

        array = null;
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine("After GC Collect - GC TotalMemory: {0}", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "memory remains"? Did you expect the second line to say 0 memory is used?

Comment: Two reasons: `Debug` configuration and debugger attached.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43e75e28-37c5-4609-a8c7-2d9ffd55991a/clearing-large-arrays-from-memory?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you are running a debug build.

For debug builds, the JIT compiler keeps alive local references until the end of the defining method. (There are actually two cases where it does this: When full debug information is output for the build, in a pdb file, and when you are running a debug build from the debugger.)

If you try a release build of your code, you'll see that the memory IS released.

See [this article by Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/02/q-should-i-set-variables-to-null-to.html) for more details.